# Copy files listed in a txt document, keeping multiple files of the same name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of lists of documents generated in powershell using this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern "acrn164524" |
    group Path |
    select Name > test.txt
```

In this example it generates a list of files containing the string acrn164524 the output looks like this:

```
Name                                                             
----                                                             
C:\data\logo.eps
C:\data\invoice.docx
C:\data\special.docx
InputStream
C:\datanew\special.docx
```

I have been using

```
Get-Content "test.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "c:\destination\" -Recurse -Container -Force
}
```

However, this is an issue if two or more files have the same name and also throws a bunch of errors for any lines in the file that are not a path.

sorry if I was not clear enough I would like to keep files with the same name by appending something to the end of the file name.

Comment: Trying to put 2 files of the same name into the same destination folder would definitely cause a conflict. Same with trying to copy something that does not have a path. Perhaps the community can help better if we knew what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, since you obviously do have files with the same name in different source folders: how do you want to handle them? First match wins? Last match? Rename files? Copy with (partial) path?

Comment: Ideally I want to keep all the files directly in the destination renaming by adding a number to the end of the file names would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the *files*, not the output of `Select-String`. So let's keep the files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object {
    $_ | Select-String acrn164524 -Quiet
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-File test.txt
```

Here

- `-File` will make `Get-ChildItem` only return actual files. Think
  about using a filter like `*.txt` to reduce the workload more.
- `-Quiet` will make `Select-String` return `$true` or `$false`, which
  is perfect for `Where-Object`.

Instead of `Select-Object -ExpandProperty X` in order to retrieve an array of raw property values (as opposed to an array of PSObjects, which is what `Select-Object` would normally do), it's simpler to use `ForEach-Object X` instead.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object {
    $_ | Select-String acrn164524 -Quiet
} | ForEach-Object FullName | Out-File test.txt
```

Comment: This provides a more straightforward approach to generating `test.txt`. However, the `Path` property of `Select-String` output contains the full path of the matching files as well, so that was already covered (even if a bit clumsy). The question is about name conflicts caused by files with the same name in different source folders. A different way of creating the same list of files does not resolve this issue.

Comment: That's true. I kind-of dismissed the grouping because the OP merely stated *"it generates a list of files containing the string acrn164524"* and did not clarify the need or reason for grouping anything with a single word. So I deemed it unnecessary, but you are probably right.

Comment: This is a better way of creating the list of files! Thanks! I will update the script that generated the file lists accordingly! Also thanks for the tip about the filter!